# How to save the logcat of android in a text file from a DOS prompt?

Tags: android, dos, logcat, android-logcat

I'm developing a mobile app using Android. I'm using Eclipse Pulsar for development. I'm using Windows XP. I want to save the logcat in a file.

When I'm taking from Eclipse Pulsar. It missed some lines. So, I try to take it from the DOS prompt.

I type the following commands in dos prompt but the file is created there is no data in file. I attached the picture file of my DOS prompt.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
adb shell logcat -t 500 > D:\1.txt
```

Where -t param is count of lines from log

Comment: From the place where your adb utility located, see platform-tools folder inside android sdk

Answer (score 3):

if you know the device Id

```
adb -s 120f1f61 logcat -d>D:\logs\log3.txt
```

or if there s only one device attached

```
adb -d logcat -d>D:\logs\log3.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This question already had answers, so you might in the future want to look for unanswered questions.